# How do I change the repository id for deployments to different environments?

Tags: maven

Right now I have this in the POM of my application to deploy to an internal maven repo for development:

```
  <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
          <id>development-repo</id>
          <name>development-repo</name>
          <url>https://artifactory/development-repo</url>
      </repository>
      <snapshotRepository>
          <id>development-repo</id>
          <name>development-repo</name>
          <url>https://artifactory/development-repo</url>
      </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

But I also have a prod repo. what I would like to do is include both in the pom, default to dev and have a way to switch to prod from command line- is this possible?

For example my poms would look like this:

```
  <!-- default to these repos so running mvn deploy will just deploy to them -->
  <repository>
      <id>development-repo</id>
      <name>development-repo</name>
      <url>https://artifactory/development-repo</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
      <id>development-repo</id>
      <name>development-repo</name>
      <url>https://artifactory/development-repo</url>
  </snapshotRepository>

  <!-- Have some way of passing switch to maven to deploy to prod repos (used by CI\CD server -->
  <repository>
      <id>production-repo</id>
      <name>production-repo</name>
      <url>https://artifactory/development-repo</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
      <id>production-repo</id>
      <name>production-repo</name>
      <url>https://artifactory/production-repo</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
```

I know maven has the concept of profiles but that seems kind of heavy handed for this? in fact I was even considering just having the CI\CD server do a text transform of the pom to replace occurrences of development-repo with production-repo, but Id like to do this the maven way if possible

Comment: Do you really want to build your project anew for the prod repository? Instead of just "promoting" your artifact from one repo to the other?

Comment: as of right now yes. and this is a specific artifactory feature- i guess i shouldnt have included artifactory in the url. as of right now I just want to switch the deployment repo dynamically

Comment: Also, even if I did promote it I would still need to change it for apps the require it as a dependency. Theyll need to be able to set the repository to the dev repo for dev deployments and the prod repo for prod deployments